# What is the functionality of "anchorwise_output" option in loss function configuration in object detection training?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

I recently updated the TensorFlow Object Detection API version in my machine, and noticed that, the "*anchorwise_output: true*" options for both *classification_loss* and *localization_loss* are removed from the default training configuration file, such as ssd_inception_v2_coco.config. If I understand the code correctly, the default value of anchorwise_output is *false*.

It seems a basic question, but I failed to find the information in any document. Is anyone could tell me how this option will impact the training, or where I could find the explanation about it? Thanks in advance.